# Executar N threads e saber quando todas terminaram de executar

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading

Tenho o seguinte problema, preciso rodar o mesmo método *N* vezes num `for` e saber quando todas as *threads* já terminaram de rodar ela.

Precisava de algo tipo assim:

```
foreach (MeuObjeto obj in lstObj)
{
    new Thread(delegate() { MetodoX(obj ); }).Start();             
}  
metodoY(); // só rodar depois que todas as thread  acima já tiverem terminado.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso usando [`Parallels (i.e. PLINQ)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [`Tasks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx). Eu recomendo que use Tasks, pois provavelmente o PLINQ em algum momento se tornará obsoleto em favor do anterior.

Veja como fazer:

- usando o método [`ForAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd383744(v=vs.110).aspx) do PLINQ... é a que fica mais simples de todas:

  ```
  lstObj.AsParallel().ForAll(MetodoX);
  metodoY();
  ```
- usando [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): chamada simples, método alterado

  ```
  var manyTasks = lstObj.Select(MetodoX); // a chamada fica símples
  Task.WhenAll(manyTasks).Wait();
  metodoY();
  ```

  Sendo que o `MetodoX` teria de ser mudado também para usar [`async` e `await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443.aspx):

  ```
  private async Task MetodoX(MeuObjeto obj)
  {
      await Task.Yield(); // primeira linha do método deve ser um Yield
  ```
- usando [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): chamada menos simples, método original

  ```
  var manyTasks = lstObj.Select(x => Task.Run(() => MetodoX(x)));
  Task.WhenAll(manyTasks).Wait();
  metodoY();
  ```

Se você ainda assim não quiser usar nenhuma dessas alternativas, não quiser usar LINQ, nem PLINQ, nem Tasks, e quiser manipular Threads na mão, então pode fazer assim:

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (string obj in lstObj)
    threads.Add(new Thread(delegate() { MetodoX(obj); }));

foreach (var thread in threads)
    thread.Start();

foreach (var thread in threads)
    thread.Join();
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível usar [`Tasks`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) conforme a recomendação do Miguel Anelo e fazer de forma simplificada sem se preocupar com o mecanismo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lstObj = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
        Parallel.ForEach(lstObj, obj => MetodoX(obj));
        Console.WriteLine("Fim"); //aqui poderia ser o MetodoY()
    }
    public static void MetodoX(int obj) {
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 3}, Valor: {obj}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nNSmzT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dM6vVZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/WaitAll.cs).

De uma maneira geral não é recomendado usar `Threads` brutas até que exista um bom motivo para usar.